# Adding external databases to settings.php using prefix

Tags: configuration, database

As per the comments in settings.php:

```
/*
 * You can also use a reference to a schema/database as a prefix. This maybe
 * useful if your Drupal installation exists in a schema that is not the default
 * or you want to access several databases from the same code base at the same
 * time.
 * Example:
 * @code
 *   'prefix' => array(
 *     'default'   => 'main.',
 *     'users'     => 'shared.',
 *     'sessions'  => 'shared.',
 *     'role'      => 'shared.',
 *     'authmap'   => 'shared.',
 *   );
 * @endcode
 */
```

So if my current simple default looks like:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'dev',
      'username' => 'dev',
      'password' => 'dev',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => false,
    ),
  ),
);
```

How would I add two tables (table1 and table2) on another database (dev1) on localhost so that they are available to drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're on the same mysql host (and you've got the appropriate permissions) you can access the tables by simply prefixing them with the schema name: `otherdatabasename.tablename`. You can even run queries joining across the two databases.

If they're on a different server you'll need to add a separate connection and specify it as part of the query by using the $options['target'] setting.

Comment: "If they're on the same mysql host (and you've got the appropriate permissions) you can access the tables by simply prefixing them with the schema name: otherdb.tablename. You can even run queries joining across the two databases" - this is exactly what I want the outcome to be. But whats the correct format in settings.php that would do this? Do you have an example?

Comment: if they're on the same host you don't need to do anything other than just refer to the table by it's full name, no new connection necessary.

Comment: Im pretty sure I had tried that but perhaps I had done it in the wrong context. Will take another look and get back.

Comment: cool, yeah post any error messages you get.